# How do I know :sign_up and account_update will be used here?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base    
  before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :email])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, bank_attributes: [:bank_name, :bank_account]])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The possible values are part of [`Devise::ParameterSanitizer`](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb#L35), which are `%i(sign_up account_update sign_in)`, and `devise_controller?` is a convenience method to check if the current controller inherits from `DeviseController`.

So basically, you end up configuring the allowed parameters for each action which devise supports using `configure_permitted_parameters` method.

However, a recommended way of doing this is to use an initializer like this:

```
# config/initializers/devise_permitted_parameters.rb
module DevisePermittedParameters

  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters
  end

  protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :email])
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:first_name, :last_name, :phone, :email, bank_attributes: [:bank_name, :bank_account]])
  end

end

DeviseController.send :include, DevisePermittedParameters
```

Comment: is it possible to know the 1st argument that which keyword exactly use here without doing google ?
for example first I use :edit instead :account_update by observing routes, using rake route command.

Comment: @MuhammadAamir: Refer to [this link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/88724e10adaf9ffd1d8dbfbaadda2b9d40de756a/lib/devise/parameter_sanitizer.rb#L35).